# Update a List with another subset List

Tags: java, performance, list, jakarta-ee

I have a simple object class which has two fields : `id` & `name`

```
public class MyObject{
   private int id; //unique id for each instance of MyObject
   private String name;

   //Setter & Getter
   ...
}
```

Now I have two `List` instances, each one holds a `List` of `MyObject`:

```
 /*it holds a list of MyObject*/
 List<MyObject> list_origin = GET_MyObject1();

 /*it holds a subset of above list, moreover, the subset objects with the 
   same 'id' as objects in above list have different 'name' value*/
 List<MyObject> list_update = GET_MyObject2();
```

`list_update` actually holds a **subset** of `list_origin`, but have updated(different) `name` value.

Now, I need to update the `list_origin` with the `list_update` (i.e. replace those objects in `list_origin` with objects in `list_update`), what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: How do you get the subset into `list_update`?

Comment: it doesn't matter how I get it, it is not related with my question.

Comment: Instead of a List<List<...>> why not have use a Map and key into each list?  List<List<..>> will be O(n^2)

Comment: If using Map could be my option I won't ask here.

Comment: well there isnt much to work with here. But a straight forward method to do it would be to create an equals method in MyObject to test equality of the objects of this type and then loop over the lists and push the update ones in the original ones.

A more ideal and better approach would be to keep track of the index ids of the objects in the original list when you extract the subset form it and later just push the updated objects back at the same index in the original list.Ofcourse if you change the original list midway doing that then indexes would also change.

Comment: @Amir Afghani, what I am asking is what I have posted above, I am not expecting anyone to read my mind that's why I told you "If using Map could be my option I won't ask here", what is wrong with telling you that using Map is out of the box for my case?

Answer (score 0):

If `list_update` is obtained using the `List.subList` method, you don't have to care about updating, as both lists will point to the same common object (will share the references).

If not, I would think about using `Map<Integer, String>` instances instead of a `List<MyObject>` instances:

```
Map<Integer, String> list_origin = GET_MyObject1();
Map<Integer, String> list_update = GET_MyObject2();
for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : list_update.entrySet()){
    list_origin.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the total procedure is likely:

1. Traverse each element of the `list_update`
2. For each element of `list_update`, find the index of corresponding element of `list_origin` that matches with `id`-`int` variable. Update the element with `ArrayList.set(index, E)` method.

This will require **`O(n^2)`** cost in total.

**To optimize:**

1. make your `MyObject` class comparable by implementing `Comparable<MyObject>`
2. sort the list  `list_origin` with `Collection.sort(list_origin)`
3. Then use `Collections.binarySearch(list, key)` method on it for finding index
   of target  object and update result.

This will require cost **`O(nlogn)`** in total.

As an exmple, your `MyObject` class will be as:

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>{
   private int id; 
   private String name;

    public MyObject(int x, String name) {
        this.id = x;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void updateName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
       return Integer.compare(id, o.id);
    }

}
```

then to update the `list_origin`:

```
Collections.sort(list_origin);

for(MyObject obj: list_update)
{
    int indx = Collections.binarySearch(list_origin, obj);
    list_origin.set(indx, obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check the Collections.binarySearch(list, key) method.

Comment: @Mellon, check the answer if it makes more sense to you now. Thank you